# How to replace a synchronous XMLHttpRequest in the onbeforeunload

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have been using a synchronous `XMLHttpRequest` in the `onbeforeunload` event to save some settings.

I see now that the synchronous `XMLHttpRequest` is deprecated.

But my attempts to get an asynchronous `XMLHttpRequest` to work in an `onbeforeunload` event fail.

By fail I mean they do not seem to be sent, or if they are, not processed on the server.

What could I be doing wrong, or is there a workaround?

Comment: what's wrong is a page navigation wont wait on asynchronous code - see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/sendBeacon for a possible workaround (depending on what you are actually sending) - with the usual warnings about browser compatibility, in other words, if you're using Internet Exploder you're SOOL

Comment: @JaromandaX: post this as an answer and I'll accept if no others have better options, Thanks! testing now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what's wrong is a page navigation wont wait on asynchronous code

for a possible workaround, see [MDN documentation for sendbeacon](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/sendBeacon) (depending on what you are actually sending) - with the usual warnings about browser compatibility, in other words, if you're using Internet Exploder you're SOOL

Comment: been trying to get this to work, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33062002/accessing-data-sent-by-sendbeacon