# Accessing data sent by sendBeacon

Tags: javascript, php

Documentation indicates `sendBeacon` sends its data via a `HTTP POST request`,
but in PHP the `$_POST` variable seems to be an empty array.

Here is my javascript code : `navigator.sendBeacon('beacon_log.php','My lost data')`

What am I doing wrong?

Update :

Found that if I use 
`navigator.sendBeacon('beacon_log.php?g_data=My data ok','Still lost!')`
I can access the gdata with `$_GET` Why would that be when the `$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=POST` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The data from `navigator.sendBeacon` is found in `$HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA`

Comment: This feature was DEPRECATED in PHP 5.6.0, and REMOVED as of PHP 7.0.0.
Source: http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.httprawpostdata.php

Answer (score 9):

here is how I get to do it:

**Front-end:** in my .js file:

```js
window.onbeforeunload = () => {
  navigator.sendBeacon('php/record-stats.php', JSON.stringify(stats));
}
```

**Back-end:** in my PHP file

```php
$request = file_get_contents('php://input');
$data = json_decode($request);
```

It was a lot of trial/errors to find it, I couldn't find any doc at the time...

Comment: seems kind of obscure but it's the only thing I could find that worked. 

Answer (score 5):

In order to get `print_r($_POST,1);` in PHP the data has to be *formatted* for an HTTP POST request:

```
window.onpagehide = function(event)
{
 var fd = new FormData(); 
 fd.append('ajax', 'beacon'); 
 fd.append('name', 'John'); 
 navigator.sendBeacon(path+'/beacon/', fd);
}
```

This will yield the desired results for `print_r($_POST,1);` in PHP.

Additionally...

- Don't use [Beacon with onbeforeunload](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onbeforeunload).
- Don't use [Beacon with onvisibilitychange](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/visibilitychange_event#Usage_notes) because of WebKit/Safari.